# Where to buy a Scandinavian birch twig whisk?

Tags: equipment

Our old birch twig whisk (from Norway) is getting old, and has lost several twigs.

Any idea how we can acquire one mail order or in the UK?

[image: Scandinavian Twig Whisk]

Comment: It is used in what fashion ? as a regular whisk ?

Comment: Yes, light stirring. It's good for sauces as the twigs make sure nothing sticks or burns in the pan

Comment: @MaxMar : it's also useful for whisking in non-stick pans, as it won't mess up the coating as much as metal will.

Comment: They make silicone whisks now for exactly that purpose @Joe. https://foodsguy.com/silicone-whisks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember my mom used to have one, found this site: https://www.townsends.us/products/birch-twig-whisk-tw338-p-1279